# Breaking result array into strings?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have column in MySQL database `answer` contain value `Mac###Windows###1###` and I want to break that into  string expected result is different strings like:

```
Mac
Windows
1
```

and I want to count the number of occurrences of each string in that database column.

I want to be print independently!

Comment: anything you tried so far ?

Comment: "thanks in advanced!" does not substitute showing prior attempts of your own.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: [`$strings = explode('###', $your_db_result);`](http://php.net/explode) and [`$num_occurrences = count($strings);`](http://php.net/count)

Answer (score 0):

Hei

```
$result = "Mac###Windows###1###";
```

In $result you can get your db result.

```
$resultArray = explode("###",$result);
```

To get total occurrence :

```
echo count($resultArray);
```

To print each occurrence :

```
print_r($resultArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to your problem please try executing following code snippet

```
$a=explode('###',$result['answer']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the column from table and use

```
$res = split("###", $column_fromdb );
```

and

```
print_r($res);
```

You will get 4 values out of which last will be empty so you can terminate using

```
if(empty($res[count($res)-1])) {
    unset($res[count($res)-1]);
}
```

I think this should help you.